# Implementing i3-like binding modes in awesomeWM

Tags: awesome-wm

I would like to have i3-like [keybinding modes](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#binding_modes) in awesomeWM. What seems to be the easiest way to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the default config, an array called `globalkeys` is set up and then "made active" via `root.keys(globalkeys)`. From a quick look at the i3 documentation, I guess your desired behaviour is something like this: you just copy the definition of `globalkeys` and call it e.g. `globalkeys2`. Then you can change the key bindings in there and switch to this mode by calling `root.keys(globalkeys2)`.